# getElementsByTagName to find tag then read string and replace text

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have spent a long time trying and working on this with no luck you see as i am fairly new to javascript. i am making a google chrome extension and i wish to block certain words on a page that has been user defined but i wish to do this without getelementbyid as the webpages they wont have my desired id. For example Have user type the words he ore her wish to block and then those words would be replaced on any webpage they visit. HElP greatly appriciated.
All i Have so far is with get element  by id and not tags

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Do you have a way of getting the specific element that the text is in or is there a way to find that element?  Or do you have to search all text on the page?

Comment: Harry Butler, if one of the answers below helped, could you please accept one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/cmontgomery/V45LS/

The secret sauce:

```
soapInTheMouth = function(node) {
  var allNodes = node.childNodes;
  $.each(allNodes, function(i,n) {
    if(n.nodeType === 3) {
      n.nodeValue = n.textContent.replace(/shit/g,'crap');
    } else {
      soapInTheMouth(n);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Text can be in any element at all, so `getElementsByTagName` won't be much use.

Instead, consider iterating through all nodes. Look for nodes of type 3 (text nodes), and replace their content.

Start at `document.body`, get its `.children[]`, and loop recursively.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more thanks with the nodes idea please

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou guys but i fixed it was simply a syntax error on my behalf